# Codificar imagen a Base 64 y despues enviarla. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

muy buen día, soy nuevo en SO, y es fascinante. Tengo un pequeño problema. Soy nuevo en PHP y aun no lo domino del todo. Realice un pequeño código que me recibe de una aplicación en Android algunos datos. Como son:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //$idmascota = $_POST['idmascota'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $fechanacimiento = $_POST['fechanacimiento'];
    $estatura = $_POST['estatura'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $peso = $_POST['peso'];
    $fotografia = $_POST['fotografia'];
    //$iddueno = $_POST['iddueno'];
    $iddueno = 'randomtext';

    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    $sql = "SELECT idmascota FROM mascota ORDER BY idmascota ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $id = 1;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        $id = $row['idmascota'];
    }

    $path = "uploads/$id.png";

    $actualpath = "http://192.168.0.5/Prueba/$path";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO mascota (nombre, fechanacimiento, estatura, sexo, peso, fotografia, iddueno) VALUES ('$nombre','$fechanacimiento','$estatura','$sexo','$peso', '$actualpath', '$iddueno')";
    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        file_put_contents($path, $fotografia) or die("Error en la escritura");
        echo "Subio imagen correctamente";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

En donde recibo datos de un perro y el campo 'fotografia' es un texto en Base64 que previamente convierto en la aplicación Android desde una imagen. Y en el campo fotografía de la BDD guardo la dirección del servidor con el 'id' que se auto incrementa en el código PHP y en la BDD para después cargarlo como si de una "src" se tratase. Pero al momento de querer implementarlo en Web, con un 'input type file' es obvio que no está en Base64 y al aplicar el "base64_decode" me genera un archivo corrupto.

Intente con el 'file_put_content' y quitar el 'base64_decode' para que se guardara la imagen, pero parece que no.

Adjunto tambien el codigo de 'dbConnect.php'.

```
<?php 
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', '');
define('DB', 'android_api');
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die ('No se puede conectar a la base de datos');
```

Y el de formulario que envía los datos, es irrelevante, pero estoy desesperado, chance y ahi está el error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
    <input type="text" name="fechanacimiento">
    <input type="text" name="estatura">
    <input type="text" name="sexo">
    <input type="text" name="peso">
    <input type="file" name="fotografia">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, y gracias :).

Comment: Si la conversión a Base64 la realizas desde la aplicación Android no creo que debas usar input type `file` sino `text`. Si usas `type="file"` deberías setear en la forma el atributo `enctype='multipart/form-data'` y leer el contenido del archivo en $_FILES según la documentación de PHP.

Comment: En Android funciona muy bien, tal vez formule mal mi pregunta, es ¿Como mando mi imagen en Base64 desde el submit, o como recibo la imagen tal cual en el archivo php para despues codificarla?"